# Translate XLIFF file into specific language xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm doing localization in my IOS App,My xcode has created xliff file from export for localization and I have multiple file like this...

[image]

as content of es.xliff is like this..

```
    </header>
<body>
  <trans-unit id="1A8-nz-WtR.placeholder">
    <source>E-mail*</source>
    <target>E-mail*</target>
    <note>Class = "UITextField"; placeholder = "E-mail*"; ObjectID = "1A8-nz-WtR";</note>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="1gB-DL-EAz.title">
    <source>Add Location</source>
    <target>Add Location</target>
    <note>Class = "UINavigationItem"; title = "Add Location"; ObjectID = "1gB-DL-EAz";</note>
```

I want to translate it in spanish which software will do that or is there any way.I had browsed but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a XLIFF Editor - check out http://xliff.brightec.co.uk/ - it's online, it's free and does the job.

You'll still need to manually translate each entry.

Comment: it is not translating ...I have to do it manually ? so why should i use this software

Comment: well, it gives you a nice interface to translate - comparing to manually editing the XML which is prone to errors. You can still use google translate or something else to translate, you just need to manually do each section.

Comment: As far as I know there are no free services that do what you want (return a translated xliff)

Comment: I'll look more into it and if there's a market for something like this I'll build a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to export XLIFF to Word (docx format), send Word document to translator on Fiverr a then import translations back from Word document to XLIFF file. https://129bit.com/home/xliff-to-word-and-back

Answer (score 0):

I found a workflow that works really well. I downloaded [Swordfish](https://www.maxprograms.com/products/swordfish.html) and signed up for their free trial. Swordfish is an XLIFF importer, editor, and exporter. Swordfish also works with machine translation engines like Google, DeepL (which I have read offers superior translation capabilities compared to Google - YMMV), Microsoft Azure, and others. I signed up with DeepL and got their API key as part of their one month free trial. I imported the API key into Swordfish. I was then able to use XLIFF files that I exported from XCode, import them into Swordfish, do the machine translate, verify the translations, then export the file. I then went to XCode and imported the updated file.